# useQuery stuck in "fetching" state

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I am using useQuery hook to fetch a list of users as:

```
  const { data, isLoading, isError, refetch, fetchStatus } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['users', queryParams],
    queryFn: () => users.getAll(queryParams),
    enabled: Boolean(queryParams),
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      console.log('fetch-users-success', data)
    }
  })
```

Whenever i create/update/delete users, i use `refetch` method to get the latest data. However, `refetch` doesn't seem to be working for some reason. The api call is definitely made (can see the api call in network tab) but for some reason, the `fetchStatus` is always stuck in fetching after the `refetch()` method call and thus the `data` is not updated.

[image]

This only happens after `refetch` method call. The initial data is fetched correctly.

Comment: can you show a codesandbox reproduction ?

Answer (score 0):

When you create/update/delete users (or any other item) you should **not** refetch the data via the `refetch` function. This is what [invalidate queries](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/query-invalidation) is for.

What should be done, is in your useMutation hook, once the post is successful, you invalidate the `users` query like this within the `onSuccess` callback function, e.g:

```
 const {
    mutate: createUser,
    isLoading: createUserLoading,
  } = useMutation(createAppUser, {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["users"] });
     // your code
    },
    onError: (data) => {
      // your code
    },
  });
```

What this will do is then trigger the refetching of data from your useQuery.